# 2nd Form Not Showing After First Selection

Tags: c#

I am not sure how to word this question, so I am just going to try to describe what I am trying to do.  I have created an MDI app that allows users to validate that the data I am pulling from spreadsheets to put into a database is accurate.  This app has an initial screen that lets the user choose the spreadsheet they want to validate and pulls the data from the database for that sheet.  It then shows a second screen when they make a selection from a dropdown list to show the data from the sheet so they can compare the two.  It works fine on the first time they select an item but not any subsequent times, it doesn't display the second screen.  I have a non-MDI version that works fine.  I declared the second form in a separate class so I can put the second form in the main window instead of on the first form and I have tried calling Dispose when the user closes the second form but it won't show the second form on any selections after the first one.  This is the code I have for creating and showing the second screen:

```
public static ExcelData showExcelData = new ExcelData(); 
Globals.showExcelData.MdiParent = this; 
Globals.showExcelData.Show();
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to show the actual code that is failing, and descibe the circumstances in detail. Also why are you using MDI when all you need is a single form? You can let the user select an appropriate filename by using the [OpenFileDialog class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog?view=netframework-4.8.1). That leaves you free to work only on a single form.

Comment: That is the code that is failing.  I am using MDI because I think it is cleaner looking than opening a second form from the first form and the user doesn't have to remember to close multiple windows.  I can't use OpenFileDialog because they are not opening a file.